# jQuery display changes with window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I recently bought a website and am having trouble with editing it to make it fit to my needs. The thing I'm trying to achieve is that making the side navbar toggle to hide the nav list when the window size gets smaller than 800 px. I'm sure this must be a ludicrously easy task to complete for many of you but I'm quite new in playing around with such codes. I hope you can take time to help with it.

Thanks in advance,

Here is the jQuery code needs to be edited.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
$("nav ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("parent");
    }
});

$(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("nav ul").slideToggle(200);
});
    $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
    if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
        $("nav ul").show();
    } else {
        $("nav ul").hide();
    }
    $("nav ul li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $("nav ul li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
        // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
    });
});

if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    $("nav ul li a").click(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("nav ul").slideToggle(200);
});    
}
```

Comment: Do you need to hide it when resizing the browser  or if it loads in a smaller screen?

Comment: I just want it to get collapsed to a bar on the top of the screen and not to show menu list till the hamburger icon being clicked.

Comment: so what is currently happening in your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: @zhon this is not my question

Comment: @PatoSalazar - It loads the sidebar nav from the left side of the window with full menu list being shown. When you hit the button, it collapses to the top of the screen. I want it to do exact opposite when the window viewport is smaller than 800px

Comment: so you want it to slide to the bottom?  can you post an  animated Gif?

Comment: @PatoSalazar - I'm not sure I can do that but simply I want it to become an inactive dropdown menu hanging at the top of the screen for the screen sizes smaller than 800px

Comment: Are you opposed to using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: @zhon - In this particular case, yes. I already have entire website template, I just need help with editing this as I have zero knowledge on jQuery..